# I would like to find all the documents stored in my database with the letter

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I would like to find all the documents stored in my database with the letter that I passed by reference in the search view, the problem is that I only accept the method that I have how I could fix it?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D117Q.png)

Comment: Please have a look at [MIninum Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update the question accordingly. Also images are a bad way of showing the code, post the actual instead.